# O365 attempting to use fetchmail to poll emails to local postfix/dovecot mails server

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, fetchmail

We currently have an application that uses IMAP/POP3 to access mail in O365; however, Microsoft has determined that they will no longer be allowing basic authentication. By do this, the application does not have the inability to use modern auth to access the mail in O365. So I am forced to build a postfix/dovecot mail server, that I'd like to use fetchmail to pull the mail from O365 into the new mail server so the application can access the mail. So my question, does fetchmail have this ability to use modern auth to poll the mail in O365 using IMAP/POP3, and if not, can anyone guide me to one that can?

Thanks

**Update**

When running fetchmail the follwoing error I get,

```
fetchmail: IMAP< A0001 OK CAPABILITY completed
fetchmail: IMAP> A0002 LOGIN "tst@domain.com" *
fetchmail: IMAP< A0002 NO LOGIN failed
fetchmail: Authorization failure on tster@domain.com@localhost
fetchmail: For help, see http://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-FAQ.html#R15
fetchmail: IMAP> A0003 LOGOUT
fetchmail: IMAP< * BYE Closing connection
fetchmail: IMAP< A0003 OK LOGOUT completed
```

Checking davmail log I'm getting the following,though not sure why I'm running into this issue.

```
2020-10-21 13:37:50,916 DEBUG [ImapConnection-42868] davmail  - < LOGIN ********
2020-10-21 13:37:50,917 WARN  [ImapConnection-42868] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - All network interfaces down or host unreachable !
2020-10-21 13:37:50,918 DEBUG [ImapConnection-42868] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: davmail.exchange.auth.O365InteractiveAuthenticator
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: davmail.exchange.auth.O365InteractiveAuthenticator
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at davmail.exchange.ExchangeSessionFactory.getInstance(ExchangeSessionFactory.java:180)
        at davmail.exchange.ExchangeSessionFactory.getInstance(ExchangeSessionFactory.java:95)
        at davmail.imap.ImapConnection.run(ImapConnection.java:113)
2020-10-21 13:37:50,920 INFO  [ImapConnection-42868] davmail.connection  - FAILED - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:42868 tst@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

[Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) will give you an IMAP/POP3 → M365 [Exchange Online](https://outlook.office365.com/) interface with OAuth (Modern Authentication). It's a Java application, but you can use [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) rather than [Oracle Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/) to avoid licensing costs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Davmail, but it seems to have a server setup option, which I got running.  Though not sure how I can get fetchmail to use davmail, I keep getting authentication failure when I attempt to have fetchmail use Davmail

Comment: To alittle more info to my above statement, both davmail and fetchmail are on the same system, and I noticed that using fetchmail with davmail, i see my username@domain.com@localhost as the login user, which is probably why it's failing though not sure how to correct that

Comment: I haven't used `fetchmail` in years, but the target username for feeding to davmail should be "user@domain"; use the verbose option in fetchmail and/or davmail to confirm that

Comment: So here's what I'm getting and hopefully you could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, using fetchmail, I'm running the following command, "fetchmail localhost -p IMAP --port 1143 -u tst@domain.com -k -v" But this is the output,fetchmail: IMAP< A0001 OK CAPABILITY completed
fetchmail: IMAP> A0002 LOGIN "tst@domain.com" *
fetchmail: IMAP< A0002 NO LOGIN failed
fetchmail: Authorization failure on tst@domain.com@localhost
fetchmail: IMAP> A0003 LOGOUT

Comment: Can't read that as a comment. Please put it into your question, ideally along with the corresponding debug/trace output from `davmail`

Comment: I've put it in my question, and hopefully you could guide me inthe right direction.